# Whern updated the picture/logo disappears from the page?

Tags: php

I'm trying to update a image in a new category but when I update it the logo/image dispersers, help pls ! Thank you

```
    if($_REQUEST["submit"] == "UPDATE")
    {
        //Put parameters into local variables
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $uniqueid = sha1($name.date("c"));
        $link = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['link']);
        $category = $_POST['cat'];
        $itemid=$_POST['hidden'];   

        if($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])
    {   
    $unlinker = selectQuery("links","*", "uniqueid =   '".$_REQUEST["un"]."'");
                @unlink("links/".$unlinker[0]["image"]);
$image = "img_".sha1($name)."-".sha1($_FILES["image"]["name"])."-".rand(100,       999).".".getExtension($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "links/".$image);
            }

        //Put data in database
        $fields    = "uniqueid,name,link,category,image";
        $values    =   **strong text**$uniqueid."','".$name."','".$link."','".$category."','".$image;
        $dbinserts = updateQuery("links",$fields,$values,"uniqueid = '".$itemid."'");
        header("Location:links.php");
        exit();
    }
          {
            include('header.php');
          }
```

Comment: This isn't part of your code `**strong text**$uniqueid."'` right?

Comment: nope it's a typo **strong text**

Answer (score 0):

You need use hidden field for image data value after fetching the data from database and assign the value to image hidden field in your html.

1. if user uploaded the image, Your condition works corect..
2. else use the hidden field value to the save the image data

Ex:...

```
if($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])
    {   
    $unlinker = selectQuery("links","*", "uniqueid =   '".$_REQUEST["un"]."'");
                @unlink("links/".$unlinker[0]["image"]);
$image = "img_".sha1($name)."-".sha1($_FILES["image"]["name"])."-".rand(100,       999).".".getExtension($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "links/".$image);
            }

else
{
$image = $_POST['hidden_image_field'];
}
```